# Cycles Render Stops Rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to make interior design. At first Cycles is really good - all I needed to do was adjust the numbers of samples; But yesterday, suddenly, when I tried to render the same file it won't render at all, it's just showing two tiles rendered.

I've tried rendering another file and it's working fine.

So, can anybody explain how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does switching to CPU rendering fix the problem? If so, it means your GPUs ran out of memory.

Comment: To be honest, it's hard to diagnose an issue like this without seeing the problem first hand, you might have accidentally made a custom render frame. On the camera view, see if there is a red box where the two tiles render, if you can see that press Ctrl+B and select outside of the camera, otherwise I'm not too sure. I hope this helps, otherwise sorry.

Comment: hi i don't use GPU rendering, it's not shown in my user preferences..only CPU rendering available there

Comment: hi there, thanks for giving your opinion..i try it again with only below 50 sample and playing with the clamp and it rendering just fine..:D

Comment: that's weird...

Comment: If you give me the blender file, I can see if I can find anything wrong...

Comment: I have the same issue, in Blender Cycles 2.72, with CPU and GPU rendering.